# How to Pass data between two sibling components?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

```
<container>
  <navbar>
    <summary></summary>
    <child-summary><child-summary>
  </navbar>
  <content></content>
</container>
```

So, in  I have a select that do send value to  and .

OnSelect method is well fired with (change) inside  component.

So, I tried with @Input, @Output and @EventEmitter directives, but I don't see how retrieve the event as @Input of the component, unless to go on parent/child pattern. All examples I've founded has a relation between component.

EDIT : Example with BehaviorSubject not working (all connected service to API works well, only observable is fired at start but not when select has value changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a sample to send message between component by using `BehaviorSubject`

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('service');
currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();


  constructor() {
  }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
}
```

You can refer at https://stackblitz.com/edit/behavior-subject-2019

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating a BehaviorSubject in the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject("default message");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```